# How to allow apostrophe (') in Magento attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, mysql-indexes

I have a create attribute called **acloth'size** for product and I have enabled the **Use In Search Results Layered Navigation** option in the backend. So while doing search, I am getting MySQL error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1106:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''size_idx.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN' at line 1, query was: SELECT `acloth'size_idx`.`value`, COUNT(acloth'size_idx.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='26'
```

I am getting the error of the product attribute field name. Is there any way to allow the apostrophe (') in search for the product attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the database field name is not quoted in all queries by Magento. In this case

```
COUNT(acloth'size_idx.entity_id)
```

should have been

```
COUNT(`acloth'size_idx`.entity_id)
```

You would have to find the core file where this "count" is generated to fix this specific issue, but there might be many more.

The only reasonable solution I see is to not use any kinds of quotes in attribute codes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this:

`echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName())`